# What's the reasoning to fallback to Object's == operator when one operand is an interface?

Tags: c#

Consider the following types:

```
class A { }
class B { }
interface IC { }

A a = null; // the value doesn't matter - null or anything else, for all three
B b = null;
IC c = null;
```

The following [does **not** compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CS0019%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true):

```
var x = a == b;
```

But the following **does** compile (as I was surprised to discover):

```
var x = a == c;
```

As I understand the compiler falls back to using the default == operator, which is defined on object and thus accepts any type for its arguments. The IL looks like this (ignore the details of `ldfld`):

```
ldarg.0
ldfld class A a
ldarg.0
ldfld class IC c
ceq
stloc.0
```

In other words it uses reference equality.

My questions:

1. In terms of language design, why does this make sense? To me it doesn't, and I consider it a big pitfall.
2. If this is indeed a pitfall, shouldn't Code Analysis warn us about it? (nope - it doesn't). By the way, [ReSharper seems to have this feature](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-286954).

Comment: Do `A` and `B` really not implement `C`? Your code snippet doesn't show that they do.

Comment: @itsme86, they don't implement `IC`

Comment: Why do you think the compiler can be sure that `A` is not an instance of a subclass of `A` that *does* implement the interface?  (it can't, thus allowing the comparison)

Comment: None compile because a b and c are unassigned.

Comment: @Anon: Ok, then assign `null` to all: http://ideone.com/fxDP1n

Comment: @Anon, ok, corrected, for completeness sake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that the second line compiles is that there may be another class that derives from A and implements IC.

```
public class D : A, IC {}
...
a = new D(); c = a; var t = a == c; //t = true;
```

Classes can only inherit from one class, so you can never create a class that inherits from both A and B unless A is a descendent of B or vice-versa.

Comment: You're right, and when `A` is `sealed` it does not compile. But does it make sense to allow this? From language design perspective you could require that when doing this comparison the types must be known to match.

Comment: A third party could be designing the class D at some time after you wrote your code, so the compiler cannot know ahead of time that there might be a class at some point inheriting from A and implementing IC.  Because of single inheritance of classes the compiler can do the checking up front for the case of comparing two classes.

Comment: I'm not arguing that the compiler can know whether or not the object will implement the interface. It can't. I'm saying that a saner decision would be to fail the compilation because the compiler can't *guarantee* that the object does in fact implement the interface. I think the case where this operation makes sense is the exception, not the rule and if you want to do it - it should have to be written explicitly  (by calling Object.ReferenceEquals)

Comment: VS2012 will give a compiler warning if there is no class that inherits from A and implements IC in the solution, but it will still let you compile.  It seems like you're not the only person who thinks this could cause some problems.

Comment: It's good to know that VS2012 gives a warning; a compiler warning is a reasonable behavior.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that the `a == b` test does not compile is because the compiler has enough information to know that the test cannot possibly be ever `true` as the two classes are not in the same hierarchy. Therefore it's the equivalent of the compiler not allowing you to write a condition that is in reality a constant by mistake.

For the interface comparison the compiler sees that there is an `operator==(object, object)` that it can use, and since both `A` and `IC` are implicitly convertible to `object` that's what in fact must happen. There can very well be another type (not even necessarily a reference type) that implements `IC` so the condition is genuine.

The R# warning is one I appreciate; as the page says, equality comparison between interface types is in some cases somewhat dubious and there an extremely descriptive, simple to replace with solution: `object.ReferenceEquals`. Of course there is the counter-argument that the equality operator may have been overloaded so the test might be meaningful. Or it can simply be someone writing in a more terse style. Obviously though banning such use in the compiler is somewhat heavy-handed.

Comment: Why doesn't the compiler fall back to `operator==(object, object)` also for class types (the `a == b` case)? BTW, from the C# spec it isn't clear what the signature of `operator==` really is for a given type.

Comment: @sinelaw: Because for the classes as given, the check cannot possibly return `true`. The compiler is protecting you from writing a meaningless and misleading conditional.